# Use A-frame img assets inside javascript

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I'm using an image as a texture several times, once via the [material](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/components/material.html) component, another time in a custom component. In the latter I'm using `THREE.TextureLoader()` which cause the application to **load the image twice**. I bet there's another way.

### Current situation

HTML

```
<!-- Assets -->
<a-assets>
  <img id="my-map" src="path/to/map.jpg">
  <a-asset-item id="my-model" src=path/to/model.gltf""></a-asset-item>
</a-assets>

<!-- Entities -->
<a-box material="src: #my-map">
<a-entity gltf-model="src: #my-model" custom-component="mymap: #my-map">
```

JS

```
// custom-component extract
schema: { mymap: { type: 'map' } }
init: function() 
{
    let mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh')
    mesh.traverse( function( child ) 
    {
        if ( child.isMesh )
        {   
            let TextureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
            let mymap = TextureLoader.load( data.mymap )

            child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: mymap })
            child.material.needsUpdate = true;
        }
    })
}
```

### Question

How can I use the same image asset in the custom component without loading it twice?

Comment: I wonder if I can use [`loadImage` helper](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/27d984f2b3c49cb1e8fa1eda1038b32dcf5fd018/src/systems/material.js#L79)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research digging in ThreeJs code I've found that `TextureLoader`  relies on `ImageLoader` (see [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ff0c85921f6748de03a9dda6fe5e9d8ea1100af9/src/loaders/TextureLoader.js#L21)) which, before loading a new image, it looks into `THREE.Cache` to see if the image has already been loaded (see [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/1a1311c24ae4be0224331f5bb6ddd71ba81f2c5d/src/loaders/ImageLoader.js#L25)).

Loading images as `img` in AFrame doesn't store them in `THREE.Cache` therefore the image was loaded twice. But if you load the image as `a-asset-item` it does.

So there is no need to change anything in javascript. Just use `a-asset-item` instead of `img`.

For more info see [AFrame documentation](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/core/asset-management-system.html#how-it-works-internally)

Comment: Should have been fixed here https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/2544

Answer (score 1):

You're using `mesh.traverse()` which calls your function once per child of `mesh`. If you have two children in your mesh, it'll call `TextureLoader.load()` twice. Simply take the load call out of `traverse()`, and you should see the image loaded just once.

```
let mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh')
let TextureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader()
let mymap = TextureLoader.load( data.mymap )

mesh.traverse( function( child ) 
{
    if ( child.isMesh )
    {   
        child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: mymap })
        child.material.needsUpdate = true;
    }
})
```

Comment: That's wrong. `TextureLoader` doesn't load an image twice because it caches it. It does it through the `ImageLoader` on [this line](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/1a1311c24ae4be0224331f5bb6ddd71ba81f2c5d/src/loaders/ImageLoader.js#L47). The problem was slightly different: see my answer.